# what is the difference to refer a processor using <process ref="bean id"> tag or using <to uri="bean:id">?

Tags: apache-camel

what is the difference to refer a processor using **process** tag or using **to** tag?

```
<route id="sample"><from uri="" /><to uri="bean:mqResponseProcessor" /></route>

<route id="sample"><from uri="" /><process ref="mqResponseProcessor"/></route>
```

Answer (score 2):

If your bean is an implementation of `org.apache.camel.Processor` then there is no practical difference. However, using [bean binding](http://camel.apache.org/bean-binding.html) offers you much greater flexibility. Among others the bean

- does not have to implement `org.apache.camel.Processor`
- can offer any number of methods to invoke
- with an arbitrary method signature
- method parameter values can be transferred from the exchange using annotations like org.apache.camel.Body or org.apache.camel.Header

Using beans and bean binding is sort of like processors on steroids.

Answer (score 1):

There is no differences, both do the same job.

With the java DSL, you have the possibility to put annonymous inner class with process syntax.

```
from("direct:demo").process(new Processor() {
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        // some stuff
   }
}).to("mock:demoEnd");
```

The process syntax can also improve the readability of code :

```
<route id="sample">
  <from uri="direct:demo"/>
  <process ref="firstProcessor"/>
  <to uri="mock:otherRoute"/>
  <process ref="secondProcessor"/>
  <to uri="mock:endTest"/>
</route>
```

Vs

```
<route id="sample">
  <from uri="direct:demo"/>
  <to uri="bean:firstProcessor"/>
  <to uri="mock:otherRoute"/>
  <to uri="bean:secondProcessor"/>
  <to uri="mock:endTest"/>
</route>
```